# use regex or php function to get all characters before ":" (colon)

Tags: php, regex

I have many fields that are like this pattern:

```
    re2man: (johnny bravo)
re1man: (john smith)......

user: (firstname lastname)..
```

I wanted to use regex, or another php function to get only characters before the colon (":")

Comment: Using regular expressions for something like this is overkill.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at `explode()` to simply split the string at the ':'.

For instance, `list($username) = explode(':', $string);`

(`list()` is being used to assign just the first part of the exploded string to `$username` and discard the rest;  a longer way to do it would be:

```
$parts = explode(':', $string);
$username = $parts[0];
```

Also, you could use the extra limit parameter to indicate that you don't need the rest of the parts, like:

`list($username) = explode(':', $string, 1);`

That may or may not be faster.  Also, I would expect using `explode()` to be more efficient than some of the other regex-based solutions offered.

Answer (score 5):

Regex style:

```
preg_match('/([^:]*):/', $subject, $matches);
```

Plain string searching:

```
strstr($subject, ':', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print preg_replace('/^([^:]+)(:.*)$/', "$1", $string);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/([\w\d]+):\s+\(([\w\d\s]*\))/', $line, $matches);

$username = $matches[1];
$realname = $matches[2];
```

Of course, you should loop around this, and also check the return value of the `preg_match()` call to see if the line matched your expectations.