# delete a part of string with php

Tags: php, string, substr

i want delete a part of string. for example i have this string

```
13|5
```

and i want to reach the sub string located before the char `|`. 
it means i have this `13|5` and i want `13`. **location of `|` is unknown**.
 for example maybe the string is `125|354` and again i want `125`

```
<?php foreach($first as $key => $value){
    echo $key."</br>";
    //$key =  13|5//
    // write a function to reach 13//
}?>
```

Comment: Hope this link help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919381/use-regex-or-php-function-to-get-all-characters-before-colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use combination of [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$str = '125|354';
$newStr = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '|'));
// 125
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `explode('|', $string)`. Hope this helps.